# asp.net core TagHelper - How to change the value attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm confused with asp.net core (2.0) TagHelpers. I've got a TagHelper that is extending the `asp-for` tag helper functionality that you can use for adding an input field to a form.

I want to alter the value attribute of the final html before after the default asp-for helper has executed. Here's my attribute:

```
[HtmlTargetElement("input", Attributes = "asp-for")]
public class DateTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    [HtmlAttributeName("asp-for")]
    public ModelExpression For { get; set; }

    public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        // Process the asp-for as normal - this will set the id,name,value attributes of the input element based on the model
        base.Process(context, output);

        // Now I want to change the value attribute here
        // output.Attributes["value"] = "hello" -- won't work :(
    }

}
```

The problem is I  can't change the attribute - it's read only. I can only add new attributes.

I had a cunning plan to get the final rendered output as a string and then change it there, like this:

```
var childContent = output.Content.IsModified ? output.Content.GetContent() :
        (await output.GetChildContentAsync()).GetContent();

var newContent = // Do some string replacing here with childContent..

output.Content.SetHtmlContent(newContent);
```

But both `output.Content.GetContent()` and `(await output.GetChildContentAsync()).GetContent()` return an empty string :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `SetAttribute`:

```
output.Attributes.SetAttribute("value", "hello");
```

Comment: How did I not try that?! :)